# ImportError: no module named tinydb

Tags: python, kivy, importerror, tinydb

I am using `from tinydb import TinyDB, Query` to import the tinydb module.  This works completely fine when testing my python and kivy code.  After using buildozer to create an apk and debugging, it is saying that it crashed because of `ImportError: no module named tinydb`. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `requirement` section of your `buildozer.spec` you should add the modules your programm needs:

```
requirements = kivy,tinydb
```

This is also described in the [buildozer documentation](http://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications.html)

I'm not sure what you need, but maybe the [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) package (which is included in the python standard library) also fits your needs.

You can also download the [repository](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb/archive/master.zip) as zip. Then you can copy the `tinydb` folder from the zip into your project. With this method you do not get any updates, but it works ;)

Comment: @salmonderossi someone had a similar problem and suggested copying the module to my App directory.  Do you know how I would be able to do this?

Comment: @Azaro I updated my answer, to copy `tinydb` inside your project ;)